# Execute ajax on button click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use this jquery into a modal with a select.
When user select an option, document_fetch.php is called and some extra field are showed to user.

I'm like to use same modal to EDIT data.

If I add

```
$("#class_id").val("2").change();
```

and I open a modal select value appear correctly.

There is a way to start ajax request by clicking the button for open modal, for example?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 



    $('#class_id').change(function(){  
    
       var cnt_man_class_doc_id = $(this).val();
       var cnt_man_folder_id = <?php echo $cnt_man_folder_id; ?>;
       
       $.ajax({
            url:"document_fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{cnt_man_class_doc_id:cnt_man_class_doc_id,
                  cnt_man_folder_id:cnt_man_folder_id
                 }, 
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_product').html(data);  
                 
            }
       });
    });



 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#class_id").val("1").change();
  
$("#YourButtonId").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var cnt_man_class_doc_id = $(this).val();
var cnt_man_folder_id = <?php echo $cnt_man_folder_id; ?>;
       
       $.ajax({
            url:"document_fetch.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{cnt_man_class_doc_id:cnt_man_class_doc_id,
                  cnt_man_folder_id:cnt_man_folder_id
                 }, 
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_product').html(data);  
                 
            }
       });
       
});
```